# VM Service not connecting when debugging for iOS | Flutter macOS iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, ios-simulator

I have just set up a Ryzen Hackintosh to be able to develop for iOS as well but after tweaking my app config for having firebase working also on the iOS version, I try to debug it on the iOS Simulator and this error appears:
[image: Flutter debug console stacktrace when trying to debug the app on VsCode]

If I try to debug a fresh newly created app it will run with no problems at all, same thing happens if I debug a fresh newly created app but with Firebase in it. This exception only happens when trying to debug a quite complete app I was developing on Windows and just for Android.

Any tips? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution:

1. Opening XCode and opening the iOS folder as a project there
2. Adding the "GoogleServices-Info.plist" file via "Add Files" (right click on "Runner" in the left bar and choose "Add Files to 'Runner'") => Select the "GoogleServices-Info.plist" file